# How to plot lines and hist on the same chart in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot how customers from different groups perform over time.
I have 5 customer groups that I'm working with and I successfully plot one of the parameters on the graph as (purple, red, green, yellow, blue) lines for each group.

But now I would like to add customer quantity for each group on the same graph as 'hist' like I manually painted (grey bars) :

[image: example image]

Can you please be so kind to tell me how can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean a histogram or a bar chart?

Comment: I do not understand what the histogram should show in this case? The bar length would be in units of time then? Please read [ask] and write a clear problem description.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want the bars to be placed horizontally and show how much customers are in each group.
Like 140 customers in first group 160 in second and so on: the more customers the wider the bar.
In the bottom of the chart I will have time scale for current lines but on the top of the chart I would like to have units for group quantities.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand how your graph should look like in the end. Are the lines offset by a certain amount or may they cross at some point, i.e. would the bars centre around a certain y-coordinate, or just be evenly spread in y direction? Why don't you want the two to be in separate adjacent figures, with probably the same colour coding?

Comment: Let me describe it in more detail.
Let's say I've devided customers by the probability of using my service to 5 groups and named them accordingly.
And was looking what percentage of customers are really using the service from each group over time.
That is on the line chart now and it is fine. The offset appears because I'm smoothing the lines via moving avarage method and it is also fine.

Comment: Now I would like to have quantities of each group displayed semi-transparent on the same chart horizontally.
And it would be nice if they were centered near the values according to their names (0.0, 0.25, etc).
I will put them on the separete graph if there is no solution to put them together, 
but I want them here because quantities are as much importaint. Furthermore as number of groups grow it would be harder for colleages to switch between graphs while analizing the data.
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it is better to add the comments you have made describing your problem in the question itself...